# Python: Mortgage calculation

Tags: python

I'm trying to calculate the first part of a mortgage but I cannot get it to work. I am receiving this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Thonny\PythonProgs\class\New folder\classy.py", line 140, in <module>
    print ("Your monthly mortgage payment will be " + str(mortgage_payment))
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

```
print ("How much is the mortgage loan you are applying for: ")
        
mortgage_loan = input()

mortgage_loan = float(mortgage_loan)

        
print ("This particular mortgage will be calculated at 3% APR over a 25 year period. ")

months = 300

months = float(months)
    
mortgage_payment = (float(mortgage_loan) / float(months) )
    
print ("Your monthly mortgage payment will be " + str(mortgage_payment))
```

Comment: You appear to have done something like `str = (1,2)` previously.

Comment: What input is getting you that error? Could you post that in your question?

Comment: Not getting any errors from your code... Please provide a [mre]

Comment: @chepner Or even `print = (1,2)`, though since it seems like the other `print()` statements work, it was probably `str = (1,2)`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Yeah, that was my reason for assuming `print` was still callable.

Comment: This is the code preceding the above code.  print ("Would you like to take up any of our other options today? Please take a look below and choose: " )
str = ("Mortgages- ", "Car Insurance- ", "Pensions- ", "Holidays- ")                           
for num, value in enumerate(str, start=1):
            print (f"{num} {value}").                                                                                                                                    I would then choose one of the options which would lead into my previous code.

Comment: Well you define `str = (...)` and then try to do `str(mortgage_payment)`... Change the name of the `str` variable. And never use built-in names

Comment: Thanks that worked.  Can you help by putting the above code into a def function - just to make more effiicient and readable.  I will try and work out the Interest rate and percentage myself  :-)

Comment: Just wrap the code with `def func`...

Comment: It's asking me to define 'mortgage loan' and 'months'?  Does it also not need a return value?

Comment: mortgage_loan = input()    print ("This particular mortgage will be calculated at 3% APR over a 25 year period. ")      months = 300.   mortgage_payment = (int(mortgage_loan) / int(months) )   print ("Your monthly mortgage payment will be " + str(mortgage_payment))

Comment: It's really hard to communicate code with comments. Read about [ask] and ask a question properly. Apart, defining a function is pretty basic stuff... Try to look around for some tutorials

Comment: No problem will look into,

Comment: @BThind If there's more code to this, please edit your post and include it. It doesn't seem like the code you've posted has any issues. Even though it's breaking in this segment, it's most likely due to some segment of code beforehand

Comment: Yes I put into a function which was pretty easy.  Now for the hard bit! I've had a look at other examples but what would be the best way to calculate the interest rate at 3.00% a year?  Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what if I just wanted the actual mortgage i will be paying monthly. As in everything including the interest. The total for every block monthly payment. What's the quickest way to work it out

Based on this comment, we can slightly tweak the answer posted previously. I will separate these answers as they seemed to be two separate questions

Try the following:

```
print ("How much is the mortgage loan you are applying for: ")
mortgage_loan = input()
mortgage_loan = float(mortgage_loan)
        
print ("This particular mortgage will be calculated at 3% APR over a 25 year period. ")
months = 300
months = float(months)

#Use floor division to find out how many years there are for the mortgage
#(e.g. 24 months = 2 years, 25 months = 2 years and 1 month -> treated as 3 years)
if (months // 12 != months / 12):
    years = int(months // 12) + 1
else:
    years = int(months / 12)

mortgage_calculated = mortgage_loan
for i in range(1, years + 1):
    #Mortgage increases by 3% for each year
    mortgage_calculated *= 1.03
print("Your mortgage after " + str(years) + " years will be: " + str(mortgage_calculated))

mortgage_payment = (float(mortgage_calculated) / float(months) )
print ("Your monthly mortgage payment over this " + str(years) + "year period will be: " + str(mortgage_payment))
```

Let me know if you need clarification.

Comment: I've tried disecting your solution above.  I understand most if it but I really need to get more understanding of this section:-  if (months // 12 != months / 12):
    years = int(months // 12) + 1
else:
    years = int(months / 12)

Comment: And also the last part where mortgage_calculated *= 1.03.  I was struggling to understand where 1.03 came from?

Comment: @BThind `if (months // 12 != months / 12):` uses floor division to find out how many years there are. This checked if there's any extra months (e.g. 12 years and 3 months). If so, the mortgage will have to round up to 13 years because the 3 months spills over the 12 year mark.

Comment: @BThind 1.00 = 100% of a number (e.g. 100 * 1.00 = 100). 0.01 = 1% of a number (e.g. 100 * 0.01 = 1). Therefore, 1.03 = 103% of a number. This is logically equivalent to a 3% increase from the current number (e.g. 100 * 1.03 = 100.3). (Updated numbers used in example to make more sense)

Comment: @BThind Meant to ask, is this working as expected?

Comment: Yes it's working correctly.  Thanks for the explanation,  the modulo if statement was something I needed to look at more closely but I can see the logic behind it.  You just need to understand the mechanics I guess

Comment: @BThind Great. I'd recommend marking this question as correct so other users with similar questions can find this answer easier.

Answer (score 0):

> "I've had a look at other examples but what would be the best way to calculate the interest rate at 3.00% a year?"

Based on your comment, this actually seems to be the question. I'll answer this an hopefully it's what you're looking for.

Based on the line of code in your initial question:

```
print ("This particular mortgage will be calculated at 3% APR over a 25 year period. ")
```

Interest will be applied on a yearly bases for 25 years. Knowing this, we can use a `for` loop to calculate this and see the amount increases on a yearly basis.

Try adding the following after the segment of code you already posted:

```
#This allows you to adjust the morgage period to any amount of months
if (months // 12 != months / 12):
    years = int(months // 12) + 1
else:
    years = int(months / 12)

#This calculates the morgage this year
mortgage_increased = mortgage_loan
for i in range(1, years + 1):
    mortgage_increased *= 1.03
    print("Your mortgage after " + str(i) + " year will be: " + str(mortgage_increased))
```

All together it should look like this:

```
print ("How much is the mortgage loan you are applying for: ")
mortgage_loan = input()
mortgage_loan = float(mortgage_loan)
        
print ("This particular mortgage will be calculated at 3% APR over a 25 year period. ")
months = 300
months = float(months)
mortgage_payment = (float(mortgage_loan) / float(months) )
    
print ("Your monthly mortgage payment will be " + str(mortgage_payment))

if (months // 12 != months / 12):
    years = int(months // 12) + 1
else:
    years = int(months / 12)

mortgage_increased = mortgage_loan
for i in range(1, years + 1):
    mortgage_increased *= 1.03
    print("Your mortgage after " + str(i) + " year will be: " + str(mortgage_increased))
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks and yes that seems to work when done that way,  what if I just wanted the actual mortgage i will be paying monthly.  As in everything including the interest.  The total for every block monthly payment.  What's the quickest way to work it out